# How can I identify what tags are associated with a docker image_id?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I specify in my docker compose file that I want to use `homeassistant/home-assistant` as my image, it will use the "latest" tag.

Now ten days later, lets assume “latest” has changed. If I want to update to the current latest, that’s easy enough.  But if I later want to revert to using the same image before I updated, I have no way of knowing what “latest” was 10 days ago.

> docker images

will give me the image_id.  Since the developer of this image also tags images with version numbers, how can I find out what other tags are associated with a specific image ID?

In the grand scheme of things, I’d like to be able to rebuild all of my containers with the images I had specified as they existed on a particular date/time.  If one uses the “latest” tag in docker compos, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull all alternative tags of a docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942359/how-to-pull-all-alternative-tags-of-a-docker-image)

Answer (score 2):

Using the "latest" tag is not really considered good practice, for exactly the reason you are describing. You probably need to get a list of images with their digests.

`docker image ls IMAGE --all --digests`

Once you have the digest you can pin your image using the digest format `homeassistant/home-assistant@sha256:45bc9ec36...`. See [docker pull](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier) docs for more info.